# How to display items on a modal by clicking Angularjs ng-repeat items

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm able to display ng-repeat items. However, if I click on an item, the modal popup is blank. It doesn't display the selected items. I tried to google some solutions but I did not manage to get it right.

Here is my Html;

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>{{category.categoryName[1]}}</h1>
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="category in categories">
      <h2>{{category.categoryName}}</h2>
      <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="product in category.products track by $index">
        <div class="panel">
          <img ng-src="{{product.image}}" ng-click="showProduct(product)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            <h6 ng-click="showProduct(product)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">{{product.name}}</h6>
            <p>R{{product.price}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- More info Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" style="color: #0091EA;">{{selectedProductName}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <img ng-src="{{selectedProductImage}}">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is my Angularjs code:

```
var data = [
{
    categoryName: "Building Materials",
    products: [
    {
        name: "Corrugated Zinc Sheets",
        image: "images/roofing.jpg",
        price: 200
    },
    {
        name: "Bathtub",
        image: "images/bathtub.jpeg",
        price: 2000
    }
    ]    
},
{
    categoryName: "Solar Products",
    products: [
    {
        name: "330W Solar Panel",
        image: "images/solar2.jpg",
        price: 5500
    },
    {
        name: "150W Solar Panel",
        image: "images/solar.jpg",
        price: 3500
    }
    ]
}
];

app.controller("productsCtrl", function($scope){
 $scope.categories = data;
 // Add ids to the array objects //
 $scope.categories.forEach( function(d, i){ d.id = i+1; });

 $scope.showProduct = function(product) {
    $scope.selectedProductName = products.name;
    $scope.selectedProductImage = products.image;
}

});
```

I expect the modal to display the name and the image of the clicked item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is typo here:

```
$scope.showProduct = function(product) {
    $scope.selectedProductName = products.name;
    $scope.selectedProductImage = products.image;
}
```

replace `products` with `product`

Answer (score 0):

How do you bind the controller to your element?

Can you try

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="productsCtrl">
```